# Plot progress bar in image

Tags: r, progress-bar

I am using R to plot 24 different images about the temperature at each hour of the day.

Instead of adding a label to each plot (i.e. 00:00; 01:00, 02:00, etc), I would like to have a "progress bar" at the top of each plot which moves one step after each plot.

For example, in the top of each figure; I want to have something like this :

Plot-1.pdf: -------A-----------

Plot-2.pdf: ---------A---------

Plot-3.pdf: -----------A-------

Plot-3.pdf: -------------A-----

etc.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you looking for a heatmap?

Answer (score 0):

Below are several types of progress bars.   Is this what you're looking for?

```
#First Type ===============================

total <- 20
# create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
for(i in 1:total){
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
   # update progress bar
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)

#Second Type ==============================

total <- 20
# create progress bar
pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0,
                max = total, width = 300)

for(i in 1:total){
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
   setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/total*100, 0),
                                    "% done"))
}
close(pb)

#Third Type ==============================

# create progress bar
pb <- winProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0,
                 max = total, width = 300)

for(i in 1:total){
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
   setWinProgressBar(pb, i, title=paste( round(i/total*100, 0),
                                    "% done"))
}
close(pb)

#Fourth Type ================================

foo <- function(...){
    total <- 40
    pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
    # computation block 1
    for(i in 1:20){
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    }

    # computation block 2
    for(i in 21:total){
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    }
    close(pb)
}

# Run it             
foo()
```

Comment: I doubt it. The OP says they want to add graphical elements to a plot. Their use of the term "progress bar" is probably a bit misleading.

Comment: @joran You are right. I want some "progress bar" in each FIGURE.